# Refactoring query to avoid duplicated code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-view

I´m having some problems with my SQL view query. I´ve several duplicated pieces of query that I think it shouldn´t be as it is. This is just a section of a bigger one:

```
    WITH auditlogs ([AuditLogId], [OperationCode], [Operation], [Table], [RowId], [Timestamp], [UserUid], [UserName], [IpAddress], [OperationSet], [ContextUid], [Field], [OldValue], [NewValue]) AS
    (
        SELECT
            al.[Id] AS [AuditLogId],
            al.[Operation] as [OperationCode],
            CASE al.[Operation]
                WHEN 0 THEN 'New'  
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Update'  
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Delete'  
                ELSE 'Warning'  
            END  AS [Operation],
            al.[EntityName] AS [Table],
            CASE al.[EntityId] 
                WHEN -1 THEN NULL
                ELSE al.[EntityId] 
            END AS [RowId],
            al.[Timestamp],
            al.[UserUid],
            al.[UserName],
            al.[IpAddress],
            al.[OperationSet],
            al.[ContextUid],
            alf.[Name],
            alf.[OldValue],
            alf.[NewValue]
        FROM [AuditLog] AS al
            INNER JOIN [AuditLogField] AS alf ON alf.AuditLogId = al.Id
    )
    SELECT [AuditLogId], --- ATTACHUSERS
        [OperationCode], [Operation], [Table], [RowId], [Timestamp], alx.[UserUid], [UserName], 
        [IpAddress], [OperationSet], [ContextUid], 'User' AS [Field], null, u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName], s.Id
    FROM (
        SELECT [AuditLogId],
            [OperationCode], [Operation], [Table], [RowId], [Timestamp], [UserUid], [UserName], 
            [IpAddress], [OperationSet], [ContextUid],
            MAX(case when [Field] = 'UserUid' then [NewValue] end) AS AddedUserUid,
            MAX(case when [Field] = 'TenantId' then [NewValue] end) TenantId
        FROM [auditlogs] AS al
        WHERE al.[Table] = 'TenantUser' AND OperationCode = 0
        GROUP BY [AuditLogId], [OperationCode], [Operation], [Table], [RowId], [Timestamp], al.[UserUid], [UserName], 
            [IpAddress], [OperationSet], [ContextUid]
    ) AS alx
    INNER JOIN [User] AS u ON u.[Uid] = CAST(alx.AddedUserUid AS uniqueidentifier) 
    INNER JOIN [Tenant] AS t ON alx.TenantId = t.Id
    INNER JOIN [Subscription] AS s ON s.TenantId = t.id
UNION ALL
    SELECT al.[AuditLogId], --- DETTACHUSERS
        al.[OperationCode], al.[Operation], al.[Table], al.[RowId], al.[Timestamp], al.[UserUid], al.[UserName], 
        al.[IpAddress], al.[OperationSet], al.[ContextUid], 'User' AS [Field], null, u.[FirstName] + ' ' + u.[LastName], s.Id
    FROM [auditlogs] AS al
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM (
            SELECT [AuditLogId],
                [OperationCode], [Operation], [Table], [RowId], [Timestamp], [UserUid], [UserName], 
                [IpAddress], [OperationSet], [ContextUid],
                MAX(case when [Field] = 'UserUid' then [NewValue] end) AS AddedUserUid,
                MAX(case when [Field] = 'TenantId' then [NewValue] end) TenantId
            FROM [auditlogs] AS al
            WHERE al.[Table] = 'TenantUser' AND OperationCode = 0
            GROUP BY [AuditLogId], [OperationCode], [Operation], [Table], [RowId], [Timestamp], al.[UserUid], [UserName], 
                [IpAddress], [OperationSet], [ContextUid]
        ) AS added
        ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
    ) AS alx ON alx.RowId = al.RowId AND al.OperationCode = 2
    INNER JOIN [User] AS u ON u.[Uid] = CAST(alx.AddedUserUid AS uniqueidentifier) 
    INNER JOIN [Tenant] AS t ON alx.TenantId = t.Id
    INNER JOIN [Subscription] AS s ON s.TenantId = t.id
```

I know my view could be composed by others, I mean, split it in several smaller views in order to reuse them and avoid the duplicated sections. However I would like to know if that is a good way to do it or if there are another and better way.

Splitting it, is it the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

CTEs are a very good way to refactor code in a query.

Just one caution:  this doesn't affect performance.  SQL Server still optimizes each reference separately, for better or worse (in my opinion).  This is a known problem at Microsoft and they've even written white papers about it.  [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables), for instance, is a formal request for this optimization.

As a second comment, often when you are joining a table to a summary of itself, window functions would be more efficient.  Your query is rather complicated, so I'm not sure if this would help.

Yes, you can have more than one cte.  Here is a basic example:

```
with digits as (select 0 as digit union all select 1 as digit),
     digits2 as (select d1.digit + d2.digit*10 as num from digits d1 cross join digits d2)
select *
from digits2
```

Incidentally, this is the same idea you can use to generate sequences of numbers in SQL Server.

Comment: Then my question is, given i am using CTE, can I have more that just one in my case. I mean, I know I can have more that just one but in my code how could I do it? It is not necessary a working example, with a kind of pseudo code is ok. Thanks